# Google App Engine - socket.io throws errors before successfully connect

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, websocket, socket.io

Ok so... For a while web sockets have been implemented in the GAE flex environment.
I've got an app deployed there and everything works "sorta" fine except that sometimes

- When Connecting or
- After a random disconnect and it tries to reconnect

I get a couple of these errors:

```
POST https://XXX.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N00Ml-1&sid=XuKv8-6R2TZrIERGAAAO 400

WebSocket connection to 'wss://XXX.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=XuKv8-6R2TZrIERGAAAO' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

GET https://XXX.appspot.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=N00Ml-2&sid=XuKv8-6R2TZrIERGAAAO 400
```

I've googled a lot and tried a lot of the stuff suggested to people that had similar issues (most of them BEFORE GAE introduced websocket support).

After a couple of these errors it just connects and everything is fine... I've tried forcing transport as websocket on the client side but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Is there any fix? Should i just change cloud provider?

Not posting any code since it's the basic socket.io nodejs implementation, in fact I've tested with an empty basic implementation and it's the same thing, my best guess is they havn't implemented the load balancer correctly? Anybody has these issues? Should i go aws instead?

Comment: Hi, I'm experienced in socket.io and WebSocket. Can you attach your client and server code?
Basically I guess that you face some exception in your server-side connect method.

Comment: It is really hard to troubleshoot such issue without being able to reproduce it. I've played a little with simple setup and couldn't get these errors. I would suggest opening a technical support ticket for more visibility if you are eligible for it. The best i can come up with is that if you are having a lot of connections and instances spin up and shut constantly depending on load, connections also shut resulting in these errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this... I've posted on the socket.io github issues

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3543

And here's a link to a better explanation
https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/3612#issuecomment-656667871